# How to append to a file if it exists else create a new and write to it

Tags: go

I have a file that I would like to add some contents to. I first check if that file exists. If it does, I add contents to it. If not, I just create a new file with that name and write to it. For this, I am doing something like:

```
if _, err := os.Stat(filename); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
        ....
} else {
    f, _ := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0660);
    ....
}
```

Is it possible to make this code shorter like 1-2 liner?

Answer (score 34):

The [OpenFile](https://pkg.go.dev/os#example-OpenFile-Append) example shows how to append to existing file or create a new file.  The code is:

```
// If the file doesn't exist, create it, or append to the file
f, err := os.OpenFile("access.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get via the `OpenFile` call whether the file had to be created or not? One way I was hoping is that `err` would indicate that the file had not existent while simultaneously `file` was set to the newly created file, but both cannot be non-`nil` it seems.